# Profile2 not editable for new users

Tags: users

I have two different profile2 profiles, the usual stuff.
I just found out that creating new profiles of *type a* makes it impossible for the user to edit his profile.

**How it should be:**

The user registers and goes to his empty profile, sees edit buttons and links.

**How it is:**

The profile is empty. you see the frame for where an image belongs, but no text at all, no buttons, no links.

I took over the project with very little documentation, already existing users have full and right functionality.
I did a permission rebuild, checked them and tweaked them without any success.

The users have permission to view, edit and delete own content.

Where should I look for the problem? What could cause such behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a CTools problem, I simply applied the patch mentioned in this comment:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2336985#comment-9748735 (#16)

```
diff --git a/plugins/content_types/entity_context/entity_field.inc b/plugins/content_types/entity_context/entity_field.inc
index 5861d1c..070266e 100644
--- a/plugins/content_types/entity_context/entity_field.inc
+++ b/plugins/content_types/entity_context/entity_field.inc
@@ -129,8 +129,7 @@ function ctools_entity_field_content_type_render($subtype, $conf, $panel_args, $

   $all_values = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, $field_name, $language);
   if (!is_array($all_values)) {
-    // Do not render if the field is empty.
-    return;
+    $all_values = array();
   }

   // Reverse values.
```